# Finding largest element in a array using call by reference ( Functions & Pointers )

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

I want to find the largest element in an array using call by reference method that is functions and pointers. I am getting an error at function call. Here is my try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bigg(int *a[10],int *N);

int main()
{
    int a[10],i,N,p;
    printf("Enter the total number of elements in the array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Enter the elements in the array one by one:\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    bigg(&a,&N);    
}

void bigg(int *a[10],int *N)
{
    int i,max;
    
    max = *a[0];
    
    for(i=0;i<*N;i++)
    {
        if( *a[i] > max)
        {
            max = *a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The biggest element in the given array is: %d",max);    
}
```

Comment: Consider checking the value of `N` received from the input. You allocated enough memory only for 10 `int`'s, therefore `N` should be equal or less than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basics of pointer is not clear.
For this question it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bigg(int a[],int *N);

int main()
{
    int a[10],i,N,p;
    printf("Enter the total number of elements in the array:\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Enter the elements in the array one by one:\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    bigg(a,&N);    
}

void bigg(int a[],int *N)
{
    int i,max;
    
    max = a[0];
    
    for(i=0;i<*N;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > max)
        {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The biggest element in the given array is: %d",max);    
}
```

Comment: It's also good to clarify what changes have you made in the code.

Comment: Thank You very much sir. I got my mistake and now I am able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you're passing doesn't match the expected argument.

The function `bigg` is expecting for it's first argument an `int *[10]` which is an *array of pointers*.  You're passing it `&a` which is a *pointer to an array* and has type `int (*)[10]`.

You actually don't want either of these.  An array name is, in most contexts, converted to a pointer to its first element.  So if you pass that you'll have access to the elements.  So change your function definition to accept an `int *` for the first argument (and an `int` for the second since you're not changing `N`):

```
void bigg(int *a, int N)
{
    int i,max;
    
    max = a[0];
    
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > max)
        {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("The biggest element in the given array is: %d",max);    
}
```

And call it like this:

```
bigg(a,N);
```